# Laravel custom page for 404 exeption

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I faced a problem - I can’t render a custom view for Laravel 5.8 404 error.

I have a `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` file that I want to display to visitors.

According to Laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#custom-http-error-pages) nothing more is needed, a custom view for 404 errors should be displayed without problems.

I have service provider, here is its `boot` method:

```
public function boot ()
{

    abort (404); // if i generate a 404 error from here, everything works fine and 404.blade.php is displayed without problems

    View :: composer (['*'], function ($view) {

    abort (404); // but if i generate a 404 error from here, it displays NotFoundHttpException 

});
```

It turns out that calling `abort (404)` from an anonymous function does not allow you to display a custom view on a 404 error ???

**UPDATE**

if I generate a 404 error from an anonymous function, I get this exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with message "Uncaught Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:992
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(46): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->abort(404, '', Array)
#1 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\app\Providers\SiteViewServiceProvider.php(70): abort(404)
#2 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\app\Providers\SiteViewServiceProvider.php(42): App\Providers\SiteViewServiceProvider->getAntiLocaleURL()
#3 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Concerns\ManagesEvents.php(164): App\Providers\SiteViewServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#4 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php(344): Illuminate\View\Factory->Illuminate\View\Concerns\{closure}('composing: erro...', Array)
#5 C:\Do"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException in C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:992
```

Comment: So what happens for a 404 now with this code in place? What is the error you get?

Comment: I added an exception that I get